# Get online XSD to validate against

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Through java, im trying to get an XSD from this URL: http://awesomeshop.iktp.dk/AwesomeSchema.xsd
to validate against som xml that my user can input. But schemaFile.exists() always returns false.

what am i doing wrong?

```
URL url = new URL("http://awesomeshop.iktp.dk/AwesomeSchema.xsd");
File schemaFile = schemaFile = new File(URLDecoder.decode(url.getFile(),"UTF-8"));
```